# screen blacks out when loading a html file in web view iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to load a html file in a web view and the screen blacks out.
Hierachy of view controller are:
View

> Web View
>   Navigation Item
>   This is the tab and there is navigation controller to present the View Controller.

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[JLTBackgroundHelper getBackgroundImageForLandingView]];
    self.webView.opaque = NO;
    self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIViewController *rootVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    rootVC.title = @"Contact JLT Sport";
    rootVC.view = self.webView;
    self.viewControllers = @[rootVC];

    NSString *fileName;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // iPad-specific
        fileName = @"contact_ipad";
    } else {
        // iPhone-specific
        fileName = @"contact";
    }

    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"Assets/web"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
    NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    _webView.delegate= self;

}


- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)wv shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navType
{
    if (navType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked
        && [request.URL.scheme hasPrefix:@"http"])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Not sure whats going wrong. tried for more than 5 hours but no luck.

Comment: why are you creating a view controller in viewDidLoad? Just add the webView to the current View Controller like this [self.view addSubView:self.webView];

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
self.viewControllers = @[rootVC];
```

Try this

```
[self presentViewController:rootVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

If presenting the controller in `viewDidLoad` gives some problem, then do it in `viewDidAppear`. First of all I'm not clear why you are creating another view controller within `viewDidLoad` of a controller and adding the subview to that.

Comment: The web view was created as a weak property and changing to strong solved the issue.